Using table of anydata as a column in a table in oracle
I'm trying to pass data from one session to another.
This can be different object types.
So we store the data in in an anydata column.
Now I'm trying to change this so we can add multiple data to this procedure.
So I want a procedure with an input of table of anydata.
And then I store this type in a table.
So I can create the type like this:
create type anydatatable as table of anydata;

But when I want to store it in a table I get the error:
create table table_any (c1 number, c2 anydatatable )


ORA-22913

How can I avoid this problem ? I read about nested table xxx store as xxx but I can't get it to work with this example.

Why ANYDATA? Why not JSON or XML?

Because then we need to convert it and afterwards convert it again. We want to skip this and this is possible with anydata

The full error message is:

ORA-22913: must specify table name for nested table column or attribute


Which tells you that you must "specify [the] table name for [a] nested table column". The syntax can be found in the CREATE TABLE documentation:
create table table_any (c1 number, c2 anydatatable )
NESTED TABLE c2 STORE AS table_any__c2

fiddle
